# GitLab CI check production before deployment(two way deployment)

Tags: git, bash, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using GitLab CI with deploy tasks for review/stage/production. Deploy currently works via rsync.

Project has files in git, but they also can be changed from admin interface of app directly on production by project owner.

So i need solution for check if files changed on production server, then create new branch and push it back to repository. And then fail deploy task with message "Please fist merge production changes".

I tried to do it with bash script:

```
# $1 GITLAB_USER_ID
# $2 CI_BUILD_REF
# $3 CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE
# $4 CI_PROJECT_NAME
# $5 CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
if [[ "$1" == 1 ]] || [[ "$1" == 2 ]] || [[ "$1" == 3 ]]; then


    echo "Deploy to production server"
    mkdir "/tmp/depl_$2"
    cd "/tmp/depl_$2"
    git clone git@privategitlab.host:$3/$4.git
    git fetch --all 
    download.sh production
    git checkout -b unmerged-$2
    git commit -m "from server"
    git push -u origin unmerged-$2
else
    echo "Deploy not allowed for you"
    exit 1
fi
```

But I have 2 problems:

1. How to understand where is changed files and where they are just older version because was downloaded previous build?
2. Gitlab authentication seems that runner doesn't have rights for pushing. I believe there is mire simple solution then creating new gitlab user with ssh-key.

.

Comment: Uff, allowing manual changes in Production seems quite buggy-prone to me.

Comment: I agree, but this is some specific ideas of person who pay:) He wants to be able for changing few things even if developers unavailable for some reason.

Comment: You can maybe touch a "flag" file after deploying. Then, check the modification time for all files and compare it with that "flag" file. Those that are newer are the modified ones.

Comment: Yep, good idea. package.json updated with version bump every production deploy. Is there way to download only files newer then specified?

Comment: You can use some kind of `find` and store its output (with full path) in a file. Then, go through the list and copy those.